# JQuery: Changing style of element when Checkbox is click

Tags: jquery, checkboxfor

I have a html elements (Using MVC3 Razor)

```
       <h2 class="price">
              @Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.Price)
              @Html.Encode(@Model.Price)
       </h2>
        <div id="checkbox-price">
              @Html.CheckBoxFor(vm => vm.IncludeToPayment) Include in payment.
        </div>
```

How can I change the style of the h2 element, (in this case I want to text-decoration: line-through the items inside) when the user uncheck/check the Checkbox using JQUery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#checkbox-price input:checkbox').change(function(){
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('.price').css('text-decoration', 'line-through')
  } else {
     $('.price').css('text-decoration', 'none')
  }
})
```

**or**

```
  $('#checkbox-price input:checkbox').change(function() { 
            // or $(`input[type="checkbox"]')
            var $obj = $('.price');
            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
              $obj.css('text-decoration', 'line-through'); //or addClass                
            } else {
              $obj.css('text-decoration', 'none'); // or addClass                
            }
        })
```

Comment: how about if i have many checkboxes? is this also triggers if I checked the other checkboxes? sorry Im a beginner in JQuery

Comment: @csharplinc in that case the code should be modified, it depends on the structure of the markup.

Comment: @undefined ++1 for the quick-ness :P, Can do a minor improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple code and [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BCZh9/).

This applies for all the check boxes

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        //alert('Checked');
        $("h2").addClass('newclass');
    } else {
        //alert('Unchecked');
        $("h2").removeClass('newclass');
    }
});​
```

If you want to apply for specific check box use below

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]') to $('input.someclass)
```

​